# populating the database with image tinker/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tinker

am trying to populate the database using terminal but am getting the error below when i upload an image

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function cover_image() in Psy Shell code on line 1**

This is what i was inserting in database

```
$event=new App\Event
$event-->cover_image('/assets/photos/event4.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `-->` into `->`, like so:

`$event->cover_image('/assets/photos/event4.jpg')`

This might be what causes your error.

Then update your blade file to display the image using the string from the database:

`<img src="{{ public_path($event->conver_image) }}">`

or depending of your full path:

`<img src="{{ url('your/path'.$event->conver_image) }}">`

Comment: i corrected that but it doesnt save the image it saves a string i cant display it on the blade view it says cannot find resource

Comment: You can not same an image in the database, you can only save a path to an image (a string indeed).
In your blade file, you should do something like: `<img src="{{ public_path($event->conver_image) }}">`